# Jet lag - Effect on supernatural creatures

Tags: vampires, supernatural, werewolf

I am not sure how well we really understand jet lag in humans, but as supernatural creatures avail themselves to modern transportation I imagine they could face several problems, or try to exploit loop holes using jets to travel.

Perhaps vampires trying to outrace the sun on a fast jet, to spend more time partying or to avoid having to go to sleep. Witches performing rituals on an airplane like astronomers use to study eclipses of the sun, allowing them to have more time to perform their ritual.  Getting an extra day by jumping across the international date line etc.

I think since these are supernatural creatures, that the answer of how they might respond to jet lag could be pretty open ended and story dependent, but a lot of supernatural creatures seem have a strong circadian rhythm, or timing like lunar cycles for werewolves,  but I am curious:

What strategies might supernatural creatures might come up with to counter jet lag effects or other problems they might face from modern travel?

Comment: This seems entirely up to how your specific supernatural creatures work in your world. As a worldbuilder you can have this play out however you want. Please also keep in mind that questions asking for help generating ideas, or brainstorming are explicitly listed as off topic in our help center. We're here to help you build your world not build it for you.

Comment: Jet lag is just shortcut for the discomfort caused by a sudden mismatch between the internal circadian rhythm and the local civil time. One doesn't need to travel to experience it -- many governments make their subjects go through it twice per year by playing around with the clocks. Very few people need more than a day or so to adjust.

Comment: What makes these people "supernatural"? Are they coming into the universe from Elsewhere? Or are they natural in this world but simply have abilities most others lack?

Comment: There are tags for "vampires" and "werewolf" and mention of "witches" in the question, but these all mean very different things in the works of different writers.  If you define exactly how they each interact with local conditions then we can explore consequences - but with enough definition I suspect you will have answered the question yourself.  One consideration - some vampire legends say they cannot cross running water, yet almost all long distance flights will cross rivers, oceanic currents etc - does this mean vampires basically can't fly long distance at all?  You must decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how well we really understand jet lag in humans,

Pretty well. It's called a circadian rhythm, almost all creatures on Earth have a 24-hour version of it. Essentially, given that the Earth has a 24-hour cycle, creatures above a certain complexity need to learn how to use and adapt to that. 'Jet lag' is just a latency period were a body readjusts their circadian rhythm.

(Well, that and the placebo effect.)

As far as we can tell, we believe that (in humans) it's controlled by a part of the brain called the [suprachiasmatic nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprachiasmatic_nucleus), but like all brain chemistry, associating it with any given one part is a gross oversimplification - there are also hormonal cycles involved with it as well, etc. etc.

> What strategies might supernatural creatures might come up with to counter jet lag effects or other problems they might face from modern travel?

So ... any 'natural' creature (by which I mean any creature on the planet that has existed for a while) would naturally fall into a circadian rhythm, for efficiency if nothing else. Apex predators like wasting as little energy as possible and there's no point in hunting for prey outside of the optimal time to seek out and kill them.

As far as coping mechanisms go - well, the same ones as humans, honestly. Be well rested before traveling, reassert your new sleep patterns as fast as possible, use drugs to stimulate/relax as need be. There's no reason to assume that, just because said creatures suck blood or turn into wolves, that they would have any different coping strategies than vanilla humans.

The one exception might be if they were designed to frequently cross time zones, but that's not a natural thing, crossing multiple time zones (or the last such that it would equal multiple times zones before times zones existed) within a matter of hours only became a thing within the past century - hence the term 'jet lag' and not 'sailing lag' or 'train lag'.